# Adding a picture before abstract in extended abstract format

Tags: graphics, xetex, formatting, abstract, sidenotes

I am writing a conference paper in the Extended Abstract Format (with the `chi-ext` class, distributed by SIGCHI). The problem I am getting is to inserting a picture under the section of authors description as shown in the following image (and also how do I insert a image in the side bar on the left).

[image]

The code I have so far is:

```
\documentclass{chi-ext}
\title{CHI \LaTeX\ Ext. Abstracts Template}
\numberofauthors{6}

\author{
  \alignauthor{
    \textbf{First Author}\\
    \affaddr{AuthorCo, Inc.}\\
    \affaddr{123 Author Ave.}\\
    \affaddr{Authortown, PA 54321 USA}\\
    \email{author1@anotherco.com}
  }}

\usepackage{graphicx}   % for EPS use the graphics package instead
\usepackage{balance}    % useful for balancing the last columns
\usepackage{bibspacing} % save vertical space in references


\begin{document}

\maketitle

\begin{abstract}
In this sample we describe the formatting requirements for various SIGCHI related submissions XXXXX
\end{abstract} 

\section{XXXX}
\section{XXXX}
\end{document}
```

*Note that this example has to be compiled with XeTeX or LuaTeX because the class requires it.*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found a version of `chi-ext.cls` from 2008 on Github and another one from 2010 on code.google. So, I did a solution for each of them. You will see that the older one requires more "hand crafting", where the recent version provides a `\teaser` macro that takes the inclusion of some contet below the authors as an argument. However, for both versions the picture on the side is realized with a marginal note. For test purpose I used `\rule` as a placeholder for the pictures.

### Code 1

```
\documentclass{chi-ext} %2008/11/25
\usepackage{geometry}
  \geometry{left=6cm}
\usepackage{graphicx} %for EPS use the graphics package instead
\usepackage{balance} %useful for balancing the last columns
%\usepackage{bibspacing} %save vertical space in references
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\title{CHI \LaTeX\ Ext. Abstracts Template}
\author{%
    \textbf{First Author}\\
    AuthorCo, Inc.\\
    123 Author Ave.\\
    Authortown, PA 54321 USA\\
    \url{author1@anotherco.com}
  }
\copyrightinfo{%
Copyright is held by the author/owner(s).\\
This is a generic SIGCHI \LaTeX\ template sample.\\
The corresponding ACM copyright statement must be included.
}

\begin{document}
\twocolumn[\maketitle]
\makeauthors\marginpar{\raggedright \rule{0.95\marginparwidth}{6cm}} %Replace "\rule..." with \includegraphics[width=0.95\marginparwidth]{picname}
\par
\vspace{2em}
{\raggedright \rule{.475\textwidth}{6cm}} %\rule -> \includegraphics[width=.475\textwidth]{picname}
\par
\makecopyright
\newpage

\begin{abstract}
  In this sample we describe the formatting requirements for various SIGCHI related submissions XXXXX
\end{abstract}

\section{XXXX}
\section{XXXX}

\onecolumn %Just in case that you want to return to the original formatting
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

Note that I disabled the `bibspacing` package because it is irrelevant to the solution and canceled a bunch of macros (`\numberofauthors`, `\alignauthors`, ...) because they are simply not there in this version of the class. You may compile twice to get the pictures in the right position.

### Code 2

```
\documentclass{chi-ext} %2010/12/01
\usepackage{graphicx} %for EPS use the graphics package instead
\usepackage{balance} %useful for balancing the last columns
%\usepackage{bibspacing} %save vertical space in references
\usepackage{marginnote}
  \reversemarginpar
\usepackage{lipsum}

\title{CHI \LaTeX\ Ext. Abstracts Template}
  \numberofauthors{6}
\author{
  \alignauthor{
    \textbf{First Author}\\
    \affaddr{AuthorCo, Inc.}\\
    \affaddr{123 Author Ave.}\\
    \affaddr{Authortown, PA 54321 USA}\\
    \email{author1@anotherco.com}
  }}
\copyrightinfo{
Copyright is held by the author/owner(s).\\
This is a generic SIGCHI \LaTeX\ template sample.\\
The corresponding ACM copyright statement must be included.
}
\teaser{\rule{\textwidth}{6cm}} %Replace "\rule..." with \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{picname}

\begin{document}

\maketitle\marginnote{\centering \rule{\marginparwidth}{6cm}} %analougus to \teaser

\begin{abstract}
  In this sample we describe the formatting requirements for various SIGCHI related submissions XXXXX
\end{abstract}

\keywords
Guides, instructions, author's kit, conference publications
%Enter your keywords here

\category{H.5.m}{Information interfaces and presentation (e.g., HCI)}{Miscellaneous}.
See: \url{http://www.acm.org/about/class/1998/}
for help using the ACM Classification system.

\terms{Documentation, Standardization}

\section{XXXX}
\section{XXXX}
\clearpage
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

Also here I disabled `bibspacing` for the same reason as above and compiling twice could be necessary too.

### Output 1

[image: absgraphic_2008]

### Output 2

[image: absgraphic_2010]

Comment: That was really helpful, thanks! Just to sum up here, I was trying to use the "marginnote" without "geometry" package and found that using something like "\marginnote{NOTE_HERE}[-Xcm]" will help to position the note in the page. The "X" value is the vertical offset from the first page's line.

Comment: Thanks Ruben! just a follow up thing, if you want to add a caption to marginpar, you'd need to use \captionof{figure}{Caption goes here}, otherwise you'll get an error.

Comment: There has been another update of the template in the meantime: https://github.com/sigchi/Document-Formats/tree/master/LaTeX, and the suggested method works with it as well, as long as one doesn't forget to add `\usepackage{marginnote} \reversemarginpar`, as shown in the example.