# How to move the abstract to the left column?

Tags: formatting, abstract

My question is similar to this [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/148459/adding-a-picture-before-abstract-in-extended-abstract-format), however, instead of a picture, I wish to move the abstract section to the left column, using same document class. Can anyone help with this?

The document class can be found [here](http://chi2016.hosting.acm.org/templates/ExtendedAbstracts/chi2016-latex-extended-abstracts.tar.gz)

MWE :

```
        \documentclass{sigchi-ext}
    % Please be sure that you have the dependencies (i.e., additional
    % LaTeX packages) to compile this example.
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
    \usepackage{textcomp}
    \usepackage[scaled=.92]{helvet} % for proper fonts
    \usepackage{graphicx} % for EPS use the graphics package instead
    \usepackage{balance}  % for useful for balancing the last columns
    \usepackage{booktabs} % for pretty table rules
    \usepackage{ccicons}  % for Creative Commons citation icons
    \usepackage{ragged2e} % for tighter hyphenation

    % \usepackage{marginnote} \usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}
    % \usepackage{paralist}


    \title{SIGCHI Extended Abstracts Sample File: \underline{N}ote
      \underline{I}nitial \underline{C}aps}


    \author{%
      \alignauthor{%
        \textbf{First Author}\\
        \affaddr{University of Author} \\
        \affaddr{Authortown, CA 94022, USA} \\
        \affaddr{author1@anotherco.edu} }}


    \def\plaintitle{SIGCHI Extended Abstracts Sample File: Note Initial
      Caps} \def\plainauthor{First Author, Second Author, Third Author,
      Fourth Author, Fifth Author, Sixth Author}
    \def\plainkeywords{Authors' choice; of terms; separated; by
      semicolons; include commas, within terms only; required.}
    \def\plaingeneralterms{Documentation, Standardization}

    %% Set up our PDF with metadata
   % \hypersetup{%
    %  pdftitle={\plaintitle}, pdfauthor={\plainauthor},
     % pdfkeywords={\plainkeywords}, }

    % \reversemarginpar%

    \begin{document}

    \maketitle

    % Uncomment to disable hyphenation (not recommended)
    % https://twitter.com/anjirokhan/status/546046683331973120
    \RaggedRight{}

    % Do not change the page size or page settings.
    \begin{abstract}
    Please place me at left column
    \end{abstract}

    \end{document}
```

Comment: You can put something else there. There's nothing special about a picture. Just save it in a box, if necessary, and then `\usebox{}`. If that's not enough, please post a minimal example and provide a link to the correct version of the class i.e. the one you're using so that people don't have to track it down and offer multiple variations on their answers, as happened there.

Comment: @cfr the minimal working example is the same as the person's who asked that question. I surely know that there is nothing special about the photo, but I do not know what kind of latex command/object is appropriate to use.  About that `\usebox{}`, do you mean I put the abstract in a box and then, I put the `\usebox{}` at same place of `\teaser` for the answer of that question?

Comment: @cfr moreover, the main problem is that `\begin{absract}...\end{abstract}` is not allowed to be placed before `\begin{document}`

Comment: Probably. Who knows? You haven't even provided a link to the version of the class you are using. Or do you really need answers for every version a web-search turns up?

Comment: You can use it before `\begin{document}` if you save it in a box. But, really, if you need detailed help, you should put some effort into making it possible to help you. So far, you've not provided a minimal example or a link to a non-standard class.

Comment: @cfr I added the link for the document class

Comment: If you're required to use the class for a submission, why are you trying to change its typographical aspect? There's  no reason whatsoever for using `sigxxx` classes other than for submissions to SIG conferences.

Comment: There is really no good way to do this. The `\maketitle` command is specifically designed to hold the authors and the ACM copyright notice and nothing else. This purposefully leaves a big gap if there are few authors, but allows lots of room for many authors.  So the code of the class would have to be reworked to accommodate this, and as noted in the comments it doesn't make too much sense to use the class if you're not submitting to ACM conferences.